# using compile time constant throws error

Tags: c++

in the below program i have used static const int init. But it is throwing error 
/tmp/ccEkWmkT.o(.text+0x15d): In function `check::operation()':
: undefined reference to`check::init'

This error is coming only when used with vector. Can someone please help? what is the exact behaviour??

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class check{
static const int init=1;
public:
    check(){}
    void operation();
};

void check::operation(){
    vector<int> dummy;
    dummy.push_back(init);
}

int main(){
    check ck;
    ck.operation();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass it by reference it is "used" and you may have to define in the .cpp file so that it gets an address.

If you just use the value of the constant, you might get away with not defining it.

Answer (score 3):

"what is the exact behaviour?"

The problem is that `push_back` takes a reference parameter. You can use the *value* of a `static const int` member variable without providing a separate definition of the object, but you can't use a reference to the object itself (since it doesn't exist). The meaning of "using" the member itself is defined in the section of the standard on the One Definition Rule, 3.2/2.

One fix is to provide a definition in exactly one translation unit:

```
const int check::init;
```

If you do this, you can also choose to move the `= 1` initialization from the declaration (inside the class) to the definition (outside the class).

Another fix is to create a temporary from the member variable (this only uses the value, it doesn't care where the object is located and hence doesn't care whether it exists), then pass a reference to the temporary:

```
dummy.push_back(int(init));
```

Of course there's a potential maintenance issue there, that if the types of `init` and `dummy` both change to, say, `long long`[*], and the value changes from `1` to something bigger than `INT_MAX`, then you're in trouble. For that reason you could use `+init`, since the unary + operator also creates a temporary for its result. Readers and future maintainers might be a bit puzzled by it, though.

[*] Supposing your implementation has `long long`.

Comment: Of course the easiest fix is to define `init` like `enum { init = 1; }. That can't be used with long long, but otherwise it does not need to be defined separately, never gets a storage and compiler always creates appropriate temporary automatically if it needs one.

Comment: Another alternative that I have seen (not that I am recommending it) is using the static constant in an expression like `check::init + 0`. The addition does not require an lvalue and thus the member is not considered *used*.

Comment: @Jan: good point. That assumes there isn't anywhere in the program that genuinely needs to use the fact that `check::init` has an address. Very likely, since otherwise there would be more errors in the program than just this one, but I failed to do it :-)

Comment: @dribeas: that does avoided mentioning the type of `init` again, though, so it's a reasonable idea. `+check::init` achieves the same, I've edited that in. For that matter, there's not a whole lot wrong with `#define` other than that it doesn't get nicely hidden in the namespace of the `check` class.

Answer (score 1):

You've to provide the definition of the *static* member outside the class (in *.cpp* file) as:

```
//check.h  (same as before)
class check
{
    static const int init=1; //declaration and in-class initialization
public:
    check(){}
    void operation();
};
```

Then in `check.cpp` file, do this:

```
//check.cpp
#include "check.h"

const int check::init;  //definition
```